# Error on A2235 with constant value too large

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

How can I write this?

```
mov rax,0123456789abcdefh
```

I'm receiving "Error A2235: Constant value too large: 123456789ABCDEFh"

Using other assembler I'm getting this:

```
   0:   48 b8 ef cd ab 89 67    movabs rax,0x123456789abcdef
   7:   45 23 01
```

Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but are you assembling in 64 bit mode with a 64 bit masm?

Comment: 64 bit assembler with HJWasm

Comment: In which case why did you tag with `masm`?

Comment: I compiled the HJWasm from git, and using `hjwasm -elf64` or `-win64` assembles your code fine.

Comment: Your version might be confused by a leading zero thinking it's octal maybe? Try just `123456789abcdefh`. Also specify what version and what command you use.

Comment: @Jester. I did what you suggested and it worked ! thank you! Problem solved